# XML sorting with XSLT - namespace in the middle

Tags: xml, xslt

I've taken a sample from `xml.com` to demonstrate a problem I'm having.

I have this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--slightly modified source from xml.com -->

<winelist xmlns="urn:somesite:api:base">

    <wine grape="Chardonnay">
        <winery>Lindeman's</winery>
        <product>Bin 65</product>
        <year>1998</year>
        <prices>
        <list>6.99</list>
            <discounted>5.99</discounted>
            <case>71.50</case>
        </prices>
    </wine>

    <wine grape="Chardonnay">
        <winery>Benziger</winery>
        <product>Carneros</product>
        <year>1997</year>
        <prices>
            <list>10.99</list>
            <discounted>9.50</discounted>
            <case>114.00</case>
        </prices>
    </wine>

    <wine grape="Cabernet">
        <winery>Duckpond</winery>
        <product>Merit Selection</product>
        <year>1996</year>
        <prices>
            <list>13.99</list>
            <discounted>11.99</discounted>
            <case>143.50</case>
        </prices>
    </wine>

    <wine grape="Chardonnay">
        <winery>Kendall Jackson</winery>
        <product>Vintner's Reserve</product>
        <year>1998</year>
        <prices>
            <list>12.50</list>
            <discounted>9.99</discounted>
            <case>115.00</case>
        </prices>
    </wine>

</winelist>
```

And this XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="winelist">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates>
                <xsl:sort data-type="number" select="prices/discounted"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm trying to sort the `wine` elements by discounted price, but the transformed XML remains unsorted unless I remove the namespace from the winelist first (i.e., using just `<winelist>`).

How can the XSLT be modified such that the namespace removal by hand does not have to be applied?

Also, the wine entities in the transformed XML lack their original `grape` attributes. How can these ones be preserved? Same goes for the comments (not that important, though).

I could use another transform to remove all the namespaces first, but I don't like this two-step solution very much, and it might be source of problems with other XML sources, I think.

Can somebody help me here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing you should have to do is add the namespace to the XSLT and modify the `match="*"` template to be an [identity transform](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#copying).

Example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:x="urn:somesite:api:base" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="x:winelist">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates>
                <xsl:sort data-type="number" select="x:prices/x:discounted"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Example of `local-name()` if namespace is unknown (tested with Xalan and Saxon 6.5.5):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="*[local-name()='winelist']">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates>
                <xsl:sort data-type="number" select="*[local-name()='prices']/*[local-name()='discounted']"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Yes, that worked.  
  
BUT I never took into account that I *might not* know the namespace before coding the stylesheet.  
  
Anyway, should I assume that your identity transform is equivalent to the one shown in the other poster's reply, or there are differences between them?

Comment: @Alvein - The identity transforms are the same. `node()` includes elements (`*`), text (`text()`), processing instructions (`processing-instruction()`, and comments (`comment()`). If you don't know the namespace, you can test `local-name()`. I will add an example.

Answer (score -1):

First, to make a faithful copy of the input XML, use the following (called the "identity transform"):

```
 <xsl:template match="@*|*|processing-instruction()|comment()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*|text()|processing-instruction()|comment()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

Second, for your matcher to ignore the namespace (if that's what you really want to do), you can match by local-name:

```
<xsl:template match="*[local-name()='winelist']">
```

Or, you could have your XSLT know about the namespace and match explicitly in that namespace, which is the more usual way to do it.  The only reason you would NOT want to do it this way is if you don't know the namespace in advance.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:w="urn:somesite:api:base">
...
   <xsl:template match="w:wine">
     ...
```

Comment: Are you sure this

<xsl:template match="*[local-name()='winelist']">

works?

Because the namespace'd winelist is not matched with that.

I even think I tried that before.

Comment: @Alvein - Using `local-name()` should work fine. What processor are you using?

Comment: Well, as you see, you had to also edit the select attribute of the sort element. That wasn't obvious for me. Thanks for all.